# Underscore reject Function with IndexOf removes all objects from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have a small Angular app that I'm writing that makes use of Underscore to look over each object in an array, and remove the object if it does not match the keyword (user input).

```
$scope.search = function() {
$scope.posts = _.reject($scope.posts, function(p) {
  var i = 0;
  if ($scope.keywords.indexOf(p.author) < 0 ) {
    i++;
  }
  if ($scope.keywords.indexOf(p.id) < 0 ) {
    i++;
  }
  if(i > 0) {
    return true;
  }
});
};
```

As you can see I'm setting a counter, and then adding to the counter if the keyword is found in the index, then at the end checking the counter to return true or false to remove the object from the array. `$scope.posts` is array of objects with my data and `$scope.keywords` is the user input. I'm wanting to lookup the input from `$scope.posts.author` object and `$scope.posts.id` object.

If I remove one of the `if` statements the function performs as expected: everything not matching the keyword is removed from the array. However, as soon as I add another `if` statement to the function (as seen in my example above), ALL objects are removed from the array.

Comment: Would `filter` be a better match for this kind of thing?

Comment: `keywords` is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as though `filter` might be a better fit here:

```
$scope.posts = _.filter($scope.posts, function(p) {
  return $scope.keywords.indexOf(p.author) > -1 || $scope.keywords.indexOf(p.id) > -1;
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4xp3sm10/

Comment: Better looking code, but I get the same result as in my example. All objects removed. If I remove the logical operator and second check it works as expected.

Comment: Hi Stephen. I've updated my code a bit and provided a working example. Hope this helps.

Comment: One change I would make is to assign the results to a different variable (like `$scope.searchResults`) rather than overwriting the `$scope.posts` data source.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filter or reject it would be even easier to do it the opposite way using _.where

```
var newArray = _.where($scope.posts, {keyword : $scope.keyword});
```

There you go, one line.

**Edit:**

If you are stuck on doing it this way, here's a way you could clean it up a little.

```
$scope.posts = _.reject($scope.posts, function(p) {
  var check = false;
  if ($scope.keywords.indexOf(p.author) < 0 ) {
    check = true;
  }
  if ($scope.keywords.indexOf(p.id) < 0 ) {
    check = true;
  }
  if(i > 0) {
    return check;
  }
});
};
```

No need to use an integer like that

Comment: post objects do not have a keyword property to match against.

Comment: fill it in with whatever it needs to be, this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are rejecting rows you will want to make sure ALL conditions are true. Your code is just checking for either one to be true.

```
 $scope.search = function() {
    $scope.posts = _.reject($scope.posts, function(p) {
      return (
           ($scope.keywords.indexOf(p.author) < 0 ) &&
           ($scope.keywords.indexOf(p.id) < 0 ) 
      );
    });
 };
```